# Why does combining Perl hashes in and each expression not work?

Tags: perl, hash, iteration, concatenation

I recently encountered this and became most displeased:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each (%hash1, %hash2)) {
}
```

Gave this error: **Experimental each on scalar is now forbidden at ...**

But this, which seems to be the same operation using a superfluous variable:

```
my %h = (%hash1, %hash2);
while (my ($key, $value) = each %h) {
}
```

Compiled and worked just fine.

What's the reason for this, and is my displeasure warranted?

Comment: What is it that you mean `each` should do in that case? Take a key/value from the first hash until it runs out, and then from the second hash? Or take a key/value from each hash (i,e, 2 keys 2 values)? I assume its the first, because I am human and can understand your subtext. But Perl logic would be to add the hashes to an array, and then loop over the array, and `each`-ing the hashes in turn.

Comment: `each`'s operand must be a hash, and `(%hash1, %hash2)` isn't a hash.

Comment: I should think it would take the result of the expression (%a, %b) and push it onto the stack as a temporary and the each operator would apply to that. But I think what happens is, since Perl fluidly moves between hashes and arrays, is that (%a, %b) actually returns an array, and %c = (%a, %b) works because assigning an array to %c, gets auto converted into a hash. Still, to be consistent each should work with arrays too (grabbing two elements at a time)

Comment: Subtle but important nuance. `(%a, %b)` is not an array. It's two hashes in list context. Depending on how it's used, that list context might be interpreted as an array, but it might also be interpreted as a hash or an argument list to a function or some other thing. In your example `my %h = (%a, %b)`, at no point is an array made; the hash is assigned a value in list context, which constructs the hash from the list's constituents. This is an important distinction, because a function like `push` takes an array, and it would not accept `(%a, %b)`, because that's not an array.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Re "*It's two hashes in list context.*", It's in scalar context in the problematic code.

Comment: @Walt Howard, Re "*I should think it would take the result of the expression*", It does. The result of that expression is the number of elements in `%hash2`. It makes absolutely no sense to pass that to `each`. And that assuming `%each` takes an expression, but it doesn't. (It was permitted experimentally for a while, thus the error message.) As I said above, `each` expects a hash.

Comment: @ikegami Why do you say it is scalar context?

Comment: @TLP, In the versions of Perl that accepted an expression for `each`'s operand, the expression is evaluated in scalar context because a reference is expected. Though it's true that in the OP's version, the concept of context doesn't apply since it's not valid code.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues that come up here. First, let's deal with your immediate problem.

```
my %h = (%hash1, %hash2);
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%hash1, %hash2)) { ... }
```

[`each`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each) is actually an ordinary function in Perl, not a special syntax or something. So, as far as Perl is concerned, you're calling `each` with two arguments, not one. `each` expects either an array or hash value (basically, something that begins with `%` or `@`), which is why `each(%h)` works. You *can* create a local hash and pass that using a bit more convoluted syntax

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%{{%hash1, %hash2}})) { ... }
```

Here, we use the hashref constructor to make a new hash `{%hash1, %hash2}`. This is a scalar value that happens to point to a hash. Then we immediately dereference it with `%{...}`. Unfortunately, this causes another problem. If you try to run this code, it'll compile fine but then infinitely loop forever. To see why this is, we'll need to take a brief tangent.

`each` is a bit of an oddball in Perl. It's actually stateful and stores the so-called state of its call in the hash object. So

```
my %h = (a => 1, b => 2);
say each(%h);
say each(%h);
```

These two calls to `each` will return different values. One will return `("a", 1)` and the other will return `("b", 2)` (the order of the two returns is unspecified).

Now, your `while` condition is going to run anew every time it loops, so if we create a temporary hash at every loop iteration, and Perl is trying to store its `each` state in the hash every time, then you'll never reach the end of iteration since you'll never iterate more than once on any given hash before it's erased and replaced with a new one.

My recommendation is to just use the temporary. Even if you *could* do it with `each` and the merged hash, you'd be making a new merged hash at every loop iteration. Alternatively, you can use [`keys`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys) to simply get all of the keys as a single list. This will only happen once, since it's happening as the head of a `for` loop.

```
for my $key (keys %{{%hash1, %hash2}}) {
    my $value = $hash1{$key} // $hash2{$key};
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for `each`:

```
each HASH
each ARRAY
```

This means

```
each %NAME
each %BLOCK
each EXPR->%*

each @NAME
each @BLOCK
each EXPR->@*
```

What you have does not match any of those patterns.

---

For a while, there was an experimental feature that allowed one to use

```
each EXPR
```

as long as the expression returned a reference to a hash or array.

The experiment was a failure, so this is no longer allowed. But your code wouldn't work even in a version of Perl with this feature. Your expression (`%hash1, %hash2` in scalar context) returns the size of `%hash2` or a weird string (depending on the version of Perl), and neither of those is a reference to a hash or a reference to an array.

---

Now, you might be tempted to use

```perl
each %{ { %hash1, %hash2 } }
```

Unfortunately, that creates a new hash each time it's evaluated, so you will perpetually get the first element of this new hash.

Comment: It also accepts `each %SIMPLE_SCALAR` where `SIMPLE_SCALAR` is `$NAME`, `$BLOCK` or `$SIMPLE_SCALAR`.

Comment: is `each ARRAY` 5.12+ worth mentioning

Comment: @Neither, Added.